# Need to fetch All results from SQLite3Result to multiarray

Tags: php, sqlite

Problem related to `php` & `sql3lite`. I want to get multi-array from `SQLite3Result`. I found function exactly what I need `http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php`

I try (php code):

```
$results = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$multiarray  = $results->fetchAll(SQLITE_ASSOC);
```

But got:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Result::fetchAll() in
```

Where is the problem? Seems this function was removed from `php5`? Any alternatives to get `multiarray`? thanks

Comment: @KA_lin as you can see. I'm already include url to this manual at my question. I'm already do that I read. Seems the problem that php does not support `fetchAll()` anymore. If so, I'm searching for good alternative code to do exactly what `fetchAll()` do.

Comment: Can`t you then make a class that extends the SQLite3 class and implement fetchAll using fetcharray?

Comment: @KA_lin I can, but 1) maybe this is implemented already by somebody else 2) Why this function removed from `php`? (need the answer) 3) can always be a better alternative than to invent new bike.

Comment: In this case use what you have in a manner that is appropriate to your needs...why it was removed is beyond me, I told you how you can implement it :)

Comment: @KA_lin Okey, I will use `while ( $row = $results->fetchArray(); )`, but still thinking that it's not so elegant like included at php `fetchAll()` and multiarray

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way to fetch data from database in `SQLite3` in php

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT bar FROM foo');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: where is that array requested in the OP?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate function to get all as

```php
function sqliteFetchAll(\SQLite3Result $results, $mode = SQLITE3_ASSOC): array
{
    $multiArray = [];
    while($result = $results->fetchArray($mode)) {
        $multiArray[] = $result;
    }
    return $multiArray;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how $results could be empty here, so I removed the condition

Comment: It was a bool check, not empty, because SQLite3 returns false if SELECT didn't find anything, so first argument could be false too, that's what I wanted to prevent.

Comment: whatever SQLite3 returns won't make it after \SQLite3Result $results

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you can extend something like:

```
<?php
$x = new SQLite3_1('xx.db');
//see: http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint2/doc/modules/sqlite3.html
class SQLite3_1 extends SQLite3
{
    public function __construct($filename,int $flags = 6, string $encryption_key = "")
    {
        parent::__construct($filename,$flags,$encryption_key);
    }
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        //own implementation with a FOR (is faster than a foreach)
    }
    public function numberResults()
    {
        //helpfull
    }
}
?>
```

It is not elegant as you stated but when migrating to different servers (and different versions of PHP) you won't have headaches this way

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to read all the rows into an array:

```php
$db = new \SQLite3("database.dat", SQLITE3_OPEN_READWRITE); //open DB
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM main"); //SQL query

$resultArray = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); //temporary variable to store each row
$multiArray = array(); //array to store all rows

while($resultArray !== false){
    array_push($multiArray, $resultArray); //insert all rows to $multiArray
    $resultArray = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); //read next row
}

unset($resultArray); //unset temporary variable

//now all rows are now in $multiArray
var_dump($multiArray);
```

When no more rows are to be read, `$result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);` returns `false`. So we simply run a loop until that happens, and push each array into a multi-dimensional array `$multiArray`.

(Tested on PHP 7+)

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$multiarray = $results->fetchArray();
```

instead of

```
$multiarray = $results->fetchAll(SQLITE_ASSOC);
```

Comment: That is for fetching a row, not for fetching all rows at once